# dojo EnhancedGrid reset nestedSort

Tags: dojo

I'm using dojo (1.8) EnhancedGrid with NestedSorting for my dynamic search. Because every search can be different in the number of columns I want to reset the last sorting before I use setStore. When I have clicked to sort the grid dojo adds the last sort of the last search to the new request at the moment. I want to start without any sort everytime I use setNewDataToGrid(). Is there a way I can achieve that?

My test HTML:

```
<div id="testGrid"></div>
<span onClick="setNewDataToGrid();">test</span>
```

My grid is:

```
 require([
        "dojox/grid/EnhancedGrid",
        "dojox/data/JsonRestStore",
        "dojox/grid/enhanced/plugins/NestedSorting",
        "dojox/grid/enhanced/plugins/Exporter",
        "dojo/domReady!",
        "dojox/grid/cells/dijit"
    ], function(DataGrid, JsonRestStore) {
        var store = new JsonRestStore({target:"/basis/contact/"});
        var grid = new DataGrid({
            style:     "height: 400px;",
            store:     store,
            query:     "",
            plugins:   {"nestedSorting": true},
            structure: [
                {
                    defaultCell: { editable: false },
                    cells:       [
                        { name: "ID", field: "id", width: "50px", },
                        { name: "Name", field: "p_familienname", width: "200px"},
                    ]
                }
            ],
            selectionMode: "single"
        }, "testGrid");
        grid.startup();
    });
```

My reset function is:

```
function setNewDataToGrid() {
    require(["dojox/data/JsonRestStore"], function (JsonRestStore) {
        var grid = dijitRegistry.byId("testGrid");
        var dataStore = new JsonRestStore({target: "/basis/member/"});
        // here I'm adding the new layout with other columns
        [...]
        grid.setStructure(newColumns);
        //insert reset sort here!
        var query = "somethingnew..."
        gid.setStore(dataStore, query);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try : grid.render(); or grid.startup(); instead of setting store as empty("") everytime.
If this doesn't help go thourgh the api https://dojotoolkit.org/api/ see what properties suit your grid functionality when you are creating it, like you can add autoRender : true.
P.S. try using the new version, v1.8 has issues, especially if you are using IE.